# C#のCoreTweetを使ったAPIアクセスにプロキシを挟みたい

Tags: c#, twitter

C#のCoreTweetのドキュメントを見る限りだと、プロキシを介したリクエストはできないようなのですが、方法はありますでしょうか。

使用したいのは認証プロキシです。

HTTPクライアントで1からやるのは最後の手段として、できれば既成のライブラリを用いて認証プロキシを介したTwitterAPIアクセスを行いたいです。

また、PC自体の設定などで、全体的にプロキシを介することは避けたいです。
あくまでアカウント単位でプロキシを介したいのですが、CoreTweetでは不可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Proxy` を設定した [`ConnectionOptions`](http://coretweet.github.io/docs/classCoreTweet_1_1ConnectionOptions.html) を [`OAuth.Authorize()`](http://coretweet.github.io/docs/classCoreTweet_1_1OAuth.html#a8be0e2bd8819aa4113103bdcb251a56f) に渡すだけでは？

Comment: 見逃してました。ありがとうございます。